# Backbone Marionette Region show without render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Is it possible to put a view that is already rendered into a backbone marionette region without rendering it again?

For example:

```
region.show(myView); // This will call render on myView
```

I don't want the region to render my view again.

If I do:

```
region.attachView(myView); // This won't render myView, but it also won't show it
```

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify your use case. Typically, you'll be in one of 3 cases: a) you instantiate a new view instance and `show` it, b) the view is already present in the HTML and you use `attachView` to be able to manage events in it (e.g. clicks), c) you already have a reference to a view instance, and can simply display it with a call to `show` as in case a).

Comment: I have a view that is rendered but not yet in DOM, I just want to display it inside the region...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First override marionette ItemView constructor and render like this (if you want to use it in CollectionView and CompositeView override these methods of them too):

```
var fnCons = Marionette.ItemView.prototype.constructor,
    fnRender = Marionette.ItemView.prototype.render;
Marionette.ItemView.prototype.constructor = function(){
  this.firstRender = true;
  fnCons.apply(this,arguments);       
}

Marionette.ItemView.prototype.render = function(){
  this.firstRender = false;
  fnRender.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

And then just override default region#show, if view is `view.firstRender` is true it's not rendered yet and must render it, else no action required.

```
Marionette.Region.prototype.show = function(view){    
  this.ensureEl();

  var isViewClosed = view.isClosed || _.isUndefined(view.$el);

  var isDifferentView = view !== this.currentView;

  if (isDifferentView) {
    this.close();
  }
  // These lines changed from default marionette action
  if(view.firstRender){
    view.render();
  }else{
    // Don anything else!
  }
  // End of overrided code


  if (isDifferentView || isViewClosed) {
    this.open(view);
  }

  this.currentView = view;

  Marionette.triggerMethod.call(this, "show", view);
  Marionette.triggerMethod.call(view, "show");
}
```

**Edit**

The solution above works fine, another way is (this will assume that view is rendered) :

```
Marionette.Region.prototype.showWithoutRender = function(view){
  this.ensureEl();

  var isViewClosed = view.isClosed || _.isUndefined(view.$el);
  var isDifferentView = view !== this.currentView;

  if (view !== this.currentView) {
    this.close();
  }

  if(isViewClosed || isDifferentView){
    this.open(view);
  }
  this.currentView = view;

  Marionette.triggerMethod.call(this, "show", view);
  Marionette.triggerMethod.call(view, "show");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// assume your view is already rendered
region.ensureEl();
region.open(myView);
```

this is not recommend though, use region.show(myView) if you can. Since it's gonna close the previous view to clean up all the event listeners, etc...