# how to pass backbone-forms form to Marionette region?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-forms

I'm trying to render a backbone-forms form in a Marionette region, but it isn't showing.  However, if I append the el of the view to the body of the document, it appears.

Do you see anything I'm doing wrong here?

```
var searchForm = Backbone.Model.extend({
  schema: {
      title: { type: 'Select', options: ['title1', 'title2'] }
  }
});

var searchFormView = new Backbone.Form({
  model: searchForm
}).render();

mainLayout.menuRegion.show(searchFormView);
//also tried this: mainLayout.menuRegion.show(searchFormView.el); 
//this one worked: $("body").append(searchFormView.el);
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: The show method of Marionette should call the render method when you pass the view to it.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496732/backbone-marionette-region-show-without-render

Answer (score 1):

In Marionette, you don't need to call `render` on a view instance. That is the source or error.

Try this

```
var searchFormView = new Backbone.Form({
  model: searchForm
})

mainLayout.menuRegion.show(searchFormView);
```