# Marionette prevent region destroy

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am using Marionette region to display templates based on user radio input:(text/file).
Here is my itemview

```
var fileTemplateView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template : "#file-upload-template"
    });
```

and region defined as

```
regions : {
            composeRegion : "#compose-region",
        }
```

and event declared as

```
   events : {
   "click #msg-input-type input:radio" : "changedRadio"
    }
```

and event trigger function is

```
changedRadio : function(evt) {
            var self = this;
            var checkedObject = evt.currentTarget;
            console.log('Radio Change Event'+checkedObject.value);

            if (checkedObject.value === "file") {
                if (self.fileView === undefined) {
                    self.fileView = new fileTemplateView();
                }
                this.composeRegion.show(self.fileView, { preventDestroy: true });
            } else if (checkedObject.value === "text") {
                if (self.textView === undefined) {
                    self.textView = new textTemplateView();
                }
                this.composeRegion.show(self.textView, { preventDestroy: true });
            }
```

But preventDestroy method may not be working as defined where template is resetting on everytime radio event happen.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to show a view into the region without having the view render again?

Comment: @Vic Yup. My Case where 1)TextBox and 2)UploadFile are the options available where in case if user switches from one radio option to another and come back he should not loose text entered or uploaded file path(name) as in plain html.

Comment: I had a similar issue before, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496732/backbone-marionette-region-show-without-render

Comment: I actually ended up not using a region and whenever I need to show a view, I just append/detach the view's $el on the DOM

Answer (score 0):

The preventDestroy option prevents the swapped view from being destroyed. This doesn't mean that is won't be re-rendered the next time it is shown. Make sure you are saving the state of the view so it can be used to reconstruct the view properly the next time.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob . As you seen in the code the state of the regions are created only if doesn't exist(undefined). If i am wrong can you provide me a code example which can save my time :)